# Как будет правильнее написать SQL запрос, использовать * или перечислить поля?

Tags: sql

Как будет правильнее написать

```sql
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;
```

или же

```sql
SELECT id,user,pass FROM users LIMIT 1; (если в таблице всего 3 структуры)
```

И если в базе всегда одна запись, есть ли смысл писать в конце запроса `limit`?

Answer (score 9):

Обычно рекомендуют выбирать поля явно. Потому что * транслируется в дополнительное обращение  к системной таблице для получения списка колонок запрошенных таблиц.

Кроме того, явное указание порядка колонок позволяет оптимизировать доступ к результатам выполнения запроса.

Ограничение выборки следует применять в сочетании с сортировкой.

Comment: да, я как раз тоже пришел к такому выводу

Comment: понимание, что астериск требует лишнего шага компиляции в список полей таблицы вбито мне в голову давно. поэтому, например, убираю его в таких подзапросах:
select .. from t1 where exists (select * from t2 where ..)

Answer (score 3):

пишите * если вам нужны все или большинство полей.

`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1` вернёт вам случайную запись

Comment: Я понял, я же уточнил запись в таблице всегда будет одна, я хотел спросить, как будет быстрее обрабатываться запрос и играет оно роль.

Comment: Если в таблице всего одна запись, то любой из этих запросов будет летать. :-) Если запись не превышает размера страницы, то больше одного обращения к диску здесь не может быть.

Answer (score 2):

Как сказал уважаемый [[@msi](/users/2339/msi)](/users/2339/msi) - без разницы.

Но теоретически, как мне кажется, быстрее будет с астериском, нежели со всеми полями - в первом случае база выдаст "не думая" всю строку, а во втором случае будет делать SELECT с фильтрацией по полям.

В любом случае, наверняка, внутренний оптимизатор СУБД приведет все к одному виду.

И если в таблице строка только одна, то LIMIT 1 излишен.

Comment: см. ответ уважаемого @Modus